# Read Excel-file from sftp server

Tags: r, sftp

I would like to read an .xlsx-File from a password protected ftp-Server into my R.

With getURL I'm able to address the files and get their names, for example "sftp://datasource.eex-group.com/market_data/power/ch/derivatives/xls/2023/PowerFutureHistory_CH_2023.xlsx", but then I don't know how to read/import this xlsx-file into R.

Is it a problem, if the path name has a blank, e.g. "sftp://datasource.eex-group.com/market data/power/ch/derivatives/xls/2023/PowerFutureHistory_CH_2023.xlsx"

Comment: I see no blanks, do you mean if your `"_"` is really a space `" "`?

Comment: It might help to see the code you're using to retrieve the files from the sftp site.

Comment: First thing: can you verify that non-R tools can access and download the files in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments.

I found the answer on [Reading information from a password protected site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420506/reading-information-from-a-password-protected-site) for the password protected part and [How to simply download an Excel File directly from the Internet with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645148/how-to-simply-download-an-excel-file-directly-from-the-internet-with-r)
for downloading the excel/csv-file.

In combination it works perfectly.

```
url = "sftp://user:passwd@server:port"

file.server <- paste0(url, path.server, "Excelfile_name_server.xlsx")

file.local <- paste0(path.local, "Excelfile_name_local.xlsx")

download.file(file.server, destfile = file.local, mode = "wb")
```